# wp_enqueue_script not loading wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to make sure a specific .js file is always loaded on any page in my Wordpress site. I used the following function and added it in function.php from my theme but it does not seem to work. I can't find the "enqueue_custom_script" when inspecting the page source.

```
function enqueue_custom_script() 
{ wp_enqueue_script('public_test', '/wp-content/plugins/paytium-pro/public/js/public.js',
 array('jquery'), '1.0', true); } 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script');
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your functions.php...

```php
function enqueue_custom_script() { 

    // register public-test-js
    $filename = plugin_url('/paytium-pro/public/js/public.js');
    
    // load script in the footer to get pt scope
    wp_register_script('public-test', $filename, [], rand(), true);

    // enqueue public-test-js
    wp_enqueue_script('public-test');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script');
```

I think the problem is your trying to enqueue `public_test` but maybe it's not registered on your front end, or not registered in time before your are trying to enqueue it.

All I am doing here is registering it manually, then enqueuing it.

Tho you might consider moving `paytium-pro` plugin from `plugins` directory into must-use plugins [`mu-plugin`](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/must-use-plugins/) directory, so it always available via your theme.

If you do move to must-use plugins directory, then you'll need to change `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` function to `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time! 

I've put the mentioned code in functions.php but I'm not sure if it's working or not. When I inspect the page source of a random page, I can't find "enqueue_custom_script" is there a way to test if this is actually working?

I placed the script near the end in functions.php, should I place it in the beginning or does that not matter?

Just a quick note: This is a crucial plugin which handles payments. Sometimes (about 10 out of 100 times) the plugin can't load the .js file and the customer can't pay. But it works every time I test it on my end.

Comment: Ran out of characters.. The plugin also warns me that the JS file can't always be loaded when opening the form. I'm not using any kind of caching and I can't reproduce the problem myself. But as mentioned this only happens like 10 out of 100 times. So I have no clue what the problem is. So my guess was to make sure this .js file is always loaded.  Makes sense?

Comment: @biggydeen it should be loaded in the source code as `public-test'. Can't see why this wouldn't work. I've added a bit of debug code... try running that.

Comment: Ok, seems to work! :) 

Would this be the way to resolve my issue?

Comment: @biggydeen so if you search `public-test` in your source code, does a script tag show in your source

Comment: Yes, it is being loaded in a script tag. But it seems like the .js file cannot be found for some reason. When looking in the console (f12) I see the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (when I hover the file it links to the paytium plugin folder)

Comment: @biggydeen is the script being loaded in the header or the footer? Could be the ordering. But isn't kinda weird the plugin is not enqueuing it properly? It's a pro version from your url, do they not have any support? Seems odd to have to enqueue a file from a plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255212/discussion-between-joshmoto-and-biggydeen).